# How to interact with cisco jabber messenger with vba

Tags: vba, xmpp

My workplace uses cisco jabber as the inhouse chat program. I am looking to provide an automated reply based on a messages I receive with data I update regularly in excel.
How can I use vba to reply to a jabber message? I have been looking around but I have found no user guides.
Any help is appreciated. an example would be great. Thank you!

Comment: There are two references in `VBA` - `CUCExtensionProvider` and `CUCMessenger`. However, I can't find any information on how to use them and my attempts to interact with them all led me back to my own information (and couldn't interact with the main window). I suspect I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the user guide is this one.
https://developer.cisco.com/docs/jabber-bots/#!cisco-jabber-bot-sdk-introduction/cisco-jabber-bot-sdk-introduction
Basically the system runs over nodeJS so you cannot use VBA but you have to work with javascript, in my opinion using excel is not the suggested option and it will be a lot less painful working with native supported format like XML.

Comment: Yes,i came across this guide as well.  I dont have access to a javascript environment so Im trying to use what I have which is vba. I managed to grab the user presence using "CUCMessenger" library so Im trying to see if there is more that I can do. Thanks for your comment

Comment: XMPP is an official standard. There are XMPP libraries available pretty much much every programming lanuage. So you can also use VBA, you just need to reference a library which is compatible with VBA, or implement XMPP code yourself in VBA.